# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when add value to variable in C language

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    int lebar,jumlah,i;
    int siswa[lebar];
    int x;

    printf("Berapa Jumlah Siswa dalam Satu Kelas: ");
    scanf("%d",&lebar);

    for(i=0;i<lebar;i++){
        printf("Masukan Nilai siswa ke-%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&siswa[i]);
        jumlah=jumlah+siswa[i];
    }

    //When I add value to this variable, it starts error 
    x=20;

    printf("Jumlah Nilai total dari %d siswa adalah %d\n",lebar,jumlah);

    return 0;
}
```

Program Work well until I add value to variable x and then I run the program, it starts to error. the message in terminal is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Don't ignore the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: `int main()` is not really a correct signature for *main*, maybe `int main(void)`.

Comment: Finally, can you tell me what is the value of `lebar` when you declare the array? `int siswa[lebar];`? If you can't it's because it's value is not yet defined.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: `int main(void)` is preferred, and I've argued that `int main()`, strictly speaking, has undefined behavior, but in practice it's not going to cause any problems. (Yes, fix it, but don't waste time looking for symptoms caused by `int main()`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes of course, I didn't mean to say that this was the cause of any problems. In fact, the comment following it adresses the actual immediate issue as you know.

Comment: It appears that you haven't enabled enough compiler options to make it warn you about using `lebar` before it has been initialized.  I recommend you both turn on the warnings *and* use a memory checker such as Valgrind on your program.  Your error will be more apparent then!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Since it's an international community, we'd appreciate if your code is written in English. For example, I might have an idea of what you're trying to do, but with the variables named like that it becomes difficult to understand.

Second, let's take a look at your code. I assume you're trying to sum all values that an user would input in an array of length `lebar`. On the 5th line of your code you define an array of size `lebar` but what is `lebar` so far?

So, you have two options to solve this problem:

1) Declare `lebar` and assign a value to it BEFORE create an array of size `lebar`.

```
int main(){
    int lebar; //I'd call it size...
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&lebar);
    int siswa[lebar];
    ...
}
```

2) Dynamically allocate an array of size `lebar` (you might need to use `#include <stdlib.h>`)

```
int main(){
    int lebar; //again, I'd call it size...
    int *siswa;
    printf("Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&lebar);
    siswa = malloc(lebar * sizeof(int));
    /* rest of your code ... */
}
```

You got the array problem solved. But looking at your code, another problem can be seen: what is the initial value of `jumlah`? Since I assume you're making a sum of all input values based on the 14th line of your code, I'd recommend you to initialize `jumlah` OUTSIDE the `for` loop with the value 0. Where? Well, that's up to you to decide. It can be on its declaration

```
int jumlah = 0;
```

or somewhere outside the loop, for example before the loop:

```
int main()
{
    int jumlah;
    /* rest of your code ... */
    jumlah = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<lebar; i++){
    /* rest of your code ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The segfault is actually here.

```
scanf("%d",&siswa[i]);
```

The problem comes from here.

```
int siswa[lebar];
```

`lebar` is not initialized at that point. Uninitialized variables in C can contain anything. That means `siswa` could be of any size.

The garbage value of `lebar` used to initialize `siswa` is then overwritten by `scanf("%d",&lebar);`. The loop assumes `siswa` is as long as the new value of `lebar`, but `siswa` could be any size. `siswa[i]` might be unallocated. If so, you'll get a segfault when you try to use it.

The simple solution is to allocate memory for `siswa` after `lebar` is initialized.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

int lebar,jumlah,i;
int *siswa;

printf("Berapa Jumlah Siswa dalam Satu Kelas: ");
scanf("%d",&lebar);
siswa = malloc( lebar * sizeof(int) );
```

---

The compiler can warn you about such things, but you have to turn the warnings on. `-Wall` is a good start but, despite the name, it does not turn on all warnings. I use `-fsanitize=address -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g`. That produces...

```
test.c:7:11: warning: variable 'lebar' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
int siswa[lebar];
          ^~~~~
test.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'lebar' to silence this warning
int lebar,jumlah,i;
         ^
          = 0
1 warning generated.
```

Which points at the problem. When run and it crashes, `-fsanitize=address` will give you a stack trace.

```
==16611==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: dynamic-stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffee60c22a0 at pc 0x000109ed40c3 bp 0x7ffee60c2160 sp 0x7ffee60c1920
WRITE of size 4 at 0x7ffee60c22a0 thread T0
    #0 0x109ed40c2 in scanf_common(void*, int, bool, char const*, __va_list_tag*) (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib+0x1a0c2)
    #1 0x109ed435e in wrap_scanf (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib+0x1a35e)
    #2 0x109b3eb0e in main (/Users/schwern/tmp/./test+0x100001b0e)
    #3 0x7fff67e07114 in start (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib+0x1114)
```

It's not the easiest thing to read, but it indicates the problem is when `scanf` is called. [Here's more on the Address Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html).

Comment: Defining a variable length array with a length of 0 has undefined behavior -- which means the compiler needn't diagnose the error. `lebar` could also have a very large positive value or a negative value, either of which could cause similar symptoms.